# Calling multiple spider from a script reactor not stopping

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I have written this script to call more than one spider. It is working fine for single spider, but not for multiple spiders. I am new to Scrapy.

```
import sys
import os
c=os.getcwd()
os.chdir("myweb")
d=os.getcwd()
os.chdir(c)
sys.path.insert(0, d)
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myweb.settings'
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.settings import CrawlerSettings
from scrapy import log, signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
def stop_reactor():
        reactor.stop()
def setup_crawler(spider_name):
    crawler = Crawler(CrawlerSettings())
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(spider_name)
    dispatcher.connect(stop_reactor, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    crawler.start()

log.start(loglevel=log.DEBUG)
crawler = Crawler(CrawlerSettings())
crawler.configure()

from aqaq.aqaq.spiders.spider import aqaqspider
spider = aqaqspider(domain='aqaq.com')
setup_crawler(spider)
from aqaq.aqaq.spiders.spider2 import DmozSpider
spider=DmozSpider(domain='shoptiques.com')
setup_crawler(spider)
result = reactor.run()
print result
log.msg("------------>Running stoped")
```

Also, when one spider is running another spider starts running, and when one spider stops whole spider stops.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to setup the same crawler to hit multiple domains, it's pretty well documented here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process.

Otherwise, removing this line might fix it:

```
dispatcher.connect(stop_reactor, signal=signals.spider_closed)
```

It's stopping the entire reactor when a single spider is closed, not allowing the second spider to finish.